# draw several ablines at once with specific color scheme

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have a data frame with slopes and intercepts coming from a series of simple linear regressions. In plotting the `abline`s I want to use a color coding that is specific for all possible combinations of class and category.

Say the data frame looks as follows:

```
(intercept  <-  rnorm(n = 40, mean = 1, sd = 0.25))
(slope      <-  rnorm(n = 40, mean = 2, sd = 1))
(clss       <-  c(rep("a", 20), rep("b", 20)))
(ctg        <-  c(rep("mm", 10), rep("nn", 10), rep("mm", 10), rep("nn", 10)))
df          <-  data.frame(intercept, slope, clss, ctg)
```

I managed to plot all `abline`s using:

```
plot(1, type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
mapply(abline, df$intercept, df$slope)
```

I want to plot these lines all in say green when `clss=="a"` and `ctg=="mm"` and use different colors for the other `clss * ctg` combinations. 
Probably something like this would work:

```
by(df, paste(df$clss, df$ctg), mapply(abline, ... ))
```

But I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg       <- df
gg$color <- paste(gg$clss,".",gg$ctg,sep="")
ggplot(gg) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-10,y=-10,color=color)) +   # need this to display a legend...
  geom_abline(aes(slope=slope, intercept=intercept, color=color)) +
  xlim(0,10) + ylim(0,10) + labs(x="X",y="Y")
```

Produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out in your case you only have 4 unique `clss` and `ctg` combinations, so I just picked some random colours and modified your `mapply`

```
# get colour for each combination
x <- sample(colours(), length(unique(paste0(df$clss, df$ctg)))) 
# how many of each combination are there
q <-  aggregate(df$intercept, by=list(paste0(df$clss, df$ctg)), length)
# make a colour vector
mycols <- rep(x, q[,2])


mapply(function(x,y,z) { abline(x, y, col=z) }, 
       df$intercept, df$slope, 
       as.list(mycols) )

#You could obviously pick the colours yourself or choose a gradient
```